# como mudar as referências include em classes criadas pelo QxORM Editor?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qxorm

Iniciei hoje programar usando o QxORM para camada de persistência a título de testes, e como uso o eclipse para todos os meus projetos, já de imediato criei um primeiro projeto de testes importando no Eclipse.

Porém as classes criadas no arquivo `.cpp` fazem referência relativas aos arquivos de cabeçalho `.h` assim ao serem importados no eclipse, onde estou referenciando a pasta **src** e **include** como origem do fonte, ele não encontra os cabeçalhos.

Segue  abaixo imagem que mostra estrutura de diretórios para ficar mais claro e em seguida um par de arquivos de uma entidade:

[image: Estrutura de Diretórios]

### Arquivo .h

```
/************************************************************************************************
** File created by QxEntityEditor 1.1.9 (2016/11/07 19:30) : please, do NOT modify this file ! **
************************************************************************************************/

#ifndef _TESTE_IEP_PORTAL_ALUNO_H_
#define _TESTE_IEP_PORTAL_ALUNO_H_

#ifdef _QX_NO_PRECOMPILED_HEADER
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
#include "../include/teste_precompiled_header.gen.h" // Need to include precompiled header for the generated moc file
#endif // Q_MOC_RUN
#endif // _QX_NO_PRECOMPILED_HEADER

namespace iep {
namespace portal {
class Professor;
} // namespace portal
} // namespace iep

namespace iep {
namespace portal {

class TESTE_EXPORT Aluno : public QObject, public qx::IxPersistable
{

   Q_OBJECT
   QX_REGISTER_FRIEND_CLASS(iep::portal::Aluno)

   QX_PERSISTABLE_HPP(iep::portal::Aluno)

public:

   typedef qx::QxCollection<long, boost::shared_ptr<iep::portal::Professor> > type_professores;

protected:

   long m_id;
   QString m_nome;
   QString m_sobrenome;
   QString m_email;
   QString m_apelido;
   type_professores m_professores;

public:

   Aluno();
   Aluno(const long & id);
   virtual ~Aluno();

   long getid() const;
   QString getnome() const;
   QString getsobrenome() const;
   QString getemail() const;
   QString getapelido() const;
   type_professores getprofessores() const;
   type_professores & professores();
   const type_professores & professores() const;

   void setid(const long & val);
   void setnome(const QString & val);
   void setsobrenome(const QString & val);
   void setemail(const QString & val);
   void setapelido(const QString & val);
   void setprofessores(const type_professores & val);

   type_professores getprofessores(bool bLoadFromDatabase, const QString & sAppendRelations = QString(), QSqlDatabase * pDatabase = NULL, QSqlError * pDaoError = NULL);
   type_professores & professores(bool bLoadFromDatabase, const QString & sAppendRelations = QString(), QSqlDatabase * pDatabase = NULL, QSqlError * pDaoError = NULL);

public:

   static QString relation_professores() { return "professores"; }

public:

   static QString column_id() { return "id"; }
   static QString column_nome() { return "nome"; }
   static QString column_sobrenome() { return "sobrenome"; }
   static QString column_email() { return "email"; }
   static QString column_apelido() { return "apelido"; }

public:

   static QString table_name() { return "Aluno"; }

};

typedef qx_shared_ptr<Aluno> Aluno_ptr;
typedef qx::QxCollection<long, Aluno_ptr> list_of_Aluno;
typedef qx_shared_ptr<list_of_Aluno> list_of_Aluno_ptr;

} // namespace portal
} // namespace iep

QX_REGISTER_COMPLEX_CLASS_NAME_HPP_TESTE(iep::portal::Aluno, QObject, 0, iep_portal_Aluno)

#include "../include/iep_portal_Professor.gen.h"

#include "../custom/include/iep_portal_Aluno.h"

#endif // _TESTE_IEP_PORTAL_ALUNO_H_
```

### Arquivo cpp:

```
/************************************************************************************************
** File created by QxEntityEditor 1.1.9 (2016/11/07 19:30) : please, do NOT modify this file ! **
************************************************************************************************/

#include "../include/teste_precompiled_header.gen.h"

#include "../include/iep_portal_Aluno.gen.h"
#include "../include/iep_portal_Professor.gen.h"

#include <QxMemLeak.h>

QX_REGISTER_COMPLEX_CLASS_NAME_CPP_TESTE(iep::portal::Aluno, iep_portal_Aluno)

namespace qx {

template <>
void register_class(QxClass<iep::portal::Aluno> & t)
{
   qx::IxDataMember * pData = NULL; Q_UNUSED(pData);
   qx::IxSqlRelation * pRelation = NULL; Q_UNUSED(pRelation);
   qx::IxFunction * pFct = NULL; Q_UNUSED(pFct);
   qx::IxValidator * pValidator = NULL; Q_UNUSED(pValidator);

   t.setName("Aluno");

   pData = t.id(& iep::portal::Aluno::m_id, "id", 0);

   pData = t.data(& iep::portal::Aluno::m_nome, "nome", 0, true, true);
   pData = t.data(& iep::portal::Aluno::m_sobrenome, "sobrenome", 0, true, true);
   pData = t.data(& iep::portal::Aluno::m_email, "email", 0, true, true);
   pData = t.data(& iep::portal::Aluno::m_apelido, "apelido", 0, true, true);

   pRelation = t.relationManyToMany(& iep::portal::Aluno::m_professores, "professores", "t_qxee_Professor_Aluno", "idprofessor", "idAluno", 0);

   qx::QxValidatorX<iep::portal::Aluno> * pAllValidator = t.getAllValidator(); Q_UNUSED(pAllValidator);
}

} // namespace qx

namespace iep {
namespace portal {

QX_PERSISTABLE_CPP(Aluno)

Aluno::Aluno() : m_id(0) { ; }

Aluno::Aluno(const long & id) : m_id(id) { ; }

Aluno::~Aluno() { ; }

long Aluno::getid() const { return m_id; }

QString Aluno::getnome() const { return m_nome; }

QString Aluno::getsobrenome() const { return m_sobrenome; }

QString Aluno::getemail() const { return m_email; }

QString Aluno::getapelido() const { return m_apelido; }

Aluno::type_professores Aluno::getprofessores() const { return m_professores; }

Aluno::type_professores & Aluno::professores() { return m_professores; }

const Aluno::type_professores & Aluno::professores() const { return m_professores; }

void Aluno::setid(const long & val) { m_id = val; }

void Aluno::setnome(const QString & val) { m_nome = val; }

void Aluno::setsobrenome(const QString & val) { m_sobrenome = val; }

void Aluno::setemail(const QString & val) { m_email = val; }

void Aluno::setapelido(const QString & val) { m_apelido = val; }

void Aluno::setprofessores(const Aluno::type_professores & val) { m_professores = val; }

Aluno::type_professores Aluno::getprofessores(bool bLoadFromDatabase, const QString & sAppendRelations /* = QString() */, QSqlDatabase * pDatabase /* = NULL */, QSqlError * pDaoError /* = NULL */)
{
   if (pDaoError) { (* pDaoError) = QSqlError(); }
   if (! bLoadFromDatabase) { return getprofessores(); }
   QString sRelation = "professores";
   if (! sAppendRelations.isEmpty() && ! sAppendRelations.startsWith("->") && ! sAppendRelations.startsWith(">>")) { sRelation += "->" + sAppendRelations; }
   else if (! sAppendRelations.isEmpty()) { sRelation += sAppendRelations; }
   iep::portal::Aluno tmp;
   tmp.m_id = this->m_id;
   QSqlError daoError = qx::dao::fetch_by_id_with_relation(sRelation, tmp, pDatabase);
   if (! daoError.isValid()) { this->m_professores = tmp.m_professores; }
   if (pDaoError) { (* pDaoError) = daoError; }
   return m_professores;
}

Aluno::type_professores & Aluno::professores(bool bLoadFromDatabase, const QString & sAppendRelations /* = QString() */, QSqlDatabase * pDatabase /* = NULL */, QSqlError * pDaoError /* = NULL */)
{
   if (pDaoError) { (* pDaoError) = QSqlError(); }
   if (! bLoadFromDatabase) { return professores(); }
   QString sRelation = "professores";
   if (! sAppendRelations.isEmpty() && ! sAppendRelations.startsWith("->") && ! sAppendRelations.startsWith(">>")) { sRelation += "->" + sAppendRelations; }
   else if (! sAppendRelations.isEmpty()) { sRelation += sAppendRelations; }
   iep::portal::Aluno tmp;
   tmp.m_id = this->m_id;
   QSqlError daoError = qx::dao::fetch_by_id_with_relation(sRelation, tmp, pDatabase);
   if (! daoError.isValid()) { this->m_professores = tmp.m_professores; }
   if (pDaoError) { (* pDaoError) = daoError; }
   return m_professores;
}

} // namespace portal
} // namespace iep
```

### Configuração do path para includes:

[image: Includes]

### Configuração do Library

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Configuração Sources

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]